# Selenium - Unable to send text on the webpage which has hidden element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the webelement which is hidden in a page

```
<form method="post" action="" data-reactid="x.x.x.x">
<input class="barcode-input" data-reactid="x.x.x.x" type="text">
</form>
```

It doesn't have a hidden tag instead it is positioned @ top: -9999px;

When i try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='barcode-input'][@type='text']")).sendKeys("barcode123"+Keys.RETURN);
```

I get this

```
cause: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException, message: 'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted withCommand duration or timeout: 10.04
```

When tried to print the isDisplayed and isEnabled property for this element i get

```
isDisplayed = false,
isEnabled = true
```

The CSS style

```
input.barcode-input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: 0 none !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: -9999px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s !important;
}
```

If i disable the top css property which is shown above, i am able to see the text box. This is a webpage which is expecting user to scan a barcode and append "ENTER" keys to it.
Appending Enter keys i can use KEYS.RETURN.

But issue is with the actual text which needs to be passed to this element.

Actual page doesn't have a text box displayed on screen though since it expects user to scan barcode.

Is there a way to bring the element to focus and send keys to it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change the value of type attribute as text from hidden. The following code using javascript would work for that:

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('body')[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');");
```

Now, you are able to type on that text by using WebDriver. So, the overall code for typing with WebDriver using Java and Javascript as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('body')[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='body']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='body']")).sendKeys("Ripon: body text");
```

Comment: Hi Hiten, it didn't work. As mentioned in description type is already text. Do you want me to try as is as given above or try with getElementsByClassName('barcode-input')

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it resolved the issue

```
JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

javascript.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"barcode-input\")[0].style.top=\"1\";");

javascript.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"barcode-input\")[0].value=\"test123\";");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='barcode-input']")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);